# Is it possible to apply EF migrations only to local/in-memory data?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

Here's the type of scenario I'm thinking of as well as what I think would be a solution, but I'm not sure if it can be done.

1. Data is retrieved from a source that used a *previous format* of data; e.g. a file or disconnected database.
2. The data is loaded into a local/in-memory context.
3. Migrations are applied to the context, presumably still in memory.
4. The data is now in the current format and is applied to the database.

The "previous format" could be different table structure, fields, data types, etc. essentially anything you'd expect a typical migration to be able to handle.

Is that possible?
Is that are reasonable solution?
If so, any pointers on implementation would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The crucial hurdle is in this part

> Migrations are applied to the context

This is just not possible. Migrations are all about the store model. It compares a hash of the SSDL (Store schema definition language) of a context (edmx) to the hash that is stored in the database. If the hashes are different, the schema differences are analyzed and converted into change actions. Of course these actions are aimed at the store model.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  Is there a way to use the schema analyzers and apply their results outside of the normal migration path (or anything else along those lines)?  _Ultimately I'm really wondering how do to deal with out-of-sync data with EF._

Comment: No, there isn't, it's all internal.